# Qual o melhor local para disponibilizar arquivo de properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, propriedade

Possui um projeto Java em *Spring Boot* que faz conexão com o banco de dados. Consequentemente tenho um arquivo de propriedades application.yml com as configuração de conexão do banco de dados.

Nesse arquivo de *properties* a configuração do *database* é como a abaixo com o usuário e senha no próprio arquivo.

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@dboracle:1521/test
        username: test
        password: 1234
```

A minha dúvida e referente a disponibilizar os dados de usuário e senha em um arquivo que pode ser alterado facilmente, não esta de acordo com as políticas de segurança da minha empresa atual.

Qual o local mais adequado para disponibilizar essas informações de forma segura e que eu possa utilizá-las no meu projeto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe um local predefinido para se colocar do *application.yml*.

Sua dúvida me parece mais em como melhorar a segurança de acesso ao servidor que executa a aplicação do que em como esconder o usuário e senha de outras pessoas.

Um exemplo disso é:
O invasor entra no servidor mas não tem o usuário e senha do banco então ele fica escutando as conexões, se você não tiver utilizando https, então ele pega o usuário e senha mesmo se estiver escondido ou em outro lugar pois a aplicação precisará deles para se conectar ao banco de dados.

Você pode optar por um sistema gestor de configuração como *zookeeper*, *consul* ou mesmo o *etcd*, mas cairá na situação que citei acima.

Foque no acesso ao servidor e a segurança dele e após isso vá atrás da segurança de senhas na aplicação pois esta segunda é mais complicada do que parece.

Aqui temos ótimas considerações sobre como esconder senhas para as aplicações:

- [Esconder senhas de aplicações shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212329/hiding-password-in-shell-scripts) aqui a Jenny, foi quem escrever a resposta no stackexchange faz considerações que vão desde a importância da informação contida no banco de dados para a empresa, qual o impacto financeiro se alguém tiver acesso aos dados, ela fala também de aspectos técnicos como o usuário que você esta utilizando é administrador do banco de dados ou tem as permissões corretas para executar somente o que a aplicação precisa e por ai vai.

O último item que ela diz que é "você nunca conseguirar evitar guardar a senha em algum lugar" é que me leva a indicar para você começar a fazer a sua segurança pela periferia da sua aplicação como: quem acessa o servidor, quem pode acessar, quem acessa a rede, se é fácil entrar no servidor.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, muito interessante o link do stackexchange vou compartilhar aqui na empresa